# How to optimize the file processing?

Tags: performance, perl, sed

I'm working on a Perl/CGI script which reads an 8MB file with over 100k lines and displays it in chunks of 100 lines (using pagination).

Which one of the following will be faster

1. Storing the entire input file into an array and extracting 100 lines for each page (using array slicing)

   ```
   my @extract = @main_content[101..200];
   ```

   or
2. For each page, using the sed command to extract any 100 lines that the user wants to view.

   ```
   sed -n '101,200'p filename
   ```

Comment: If you already have some session management going on then you should store the `seek` point for each 100-line block

Comment: Try both and find out.  The answer is going to depend on your system to a large degree, and we don't have access to that.

Comment: Also, CGI and speed are not exactly synonyms. Run your script in a persistent environment.

Comment: When you say "read" is it from the disk? Is the user going to page through it at once or can they come back at any time during run time?  Are they going to go back and forth or only down the file? This 100k lines is nothing -- I just counted 400k by reading such a file with one-liner, in under half a second (eyeball-ed). Yes, you can pull it into an array, tie it, seek ... Why this quest to optimize? Please describe the problem better.

Comment: @zdim I tried, I store the content in an array then tie it and read it. For the single user or couple of user it works without any problem(i.e loads fast). But when the user count will increase or there input file size very huge(above 80 MB) my server will hang. [This is for small size file within 5 MB](http://bioserver2.physics.iisc.ernet.in/cgi-bin/repex/repex_map/repex.pl?filename=143711inputtext.txt.identical&seqflnm=143711inputtext.txt#)  And the click the standard view in the bottom of the page which is for above 8 mb with cgi response (i tried it by python cgi with using sed command).

Comment: @zdim The tool is still under developing

Comment: OK, so this file is what is served to a number of users. (I didn't get that.)  So a user requests to view a (part of that) file and they are served via CGI? That's different. I'd say that the performance problem is elsewhere, with the whole server setup.  For instance as indicated in the answer by amias channer. I don't think that micro-tuning the speed of seeking and serving 100 lines would solve it.  With how many users does it hang? Without knowing about your circumstances I'd say use the opportunity to pick up some modern approach, not CGI.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want performance then don't use CGI, try using something that keeps a persistent copy of the data in memory between requests. 8mb is tiny these days but loading for every request would not be sensible nor would scanning the whole file.  Modperl was the older way of doing this , it was a perl interpreter embedded in the webserver , the newer way is to use catalyst or dancer, instructions for those are outside the scope of this reply.  You could get away with using CGI if this was only to be use occasionally and was password protected to limit use.